# How to simply get RGB values in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I would like to obtain the RGB values for any pixel I choose or loop. This is currently how I achieve it.

```
Vec3b color = img.at<Vec3b>(Point(i, j));
```

and for the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        Vec3b color = img.at<Vec3b>(Point(i,j));
        img.at<Vec3b>(Point(i, j)) = color;
    }
}
```

**But when I apply the Canny/cvtColor function it all messes up**. An Unhandled exception at memory location pops up.

I ran more tests, and found that the loop just works fine with the height, but as for the width it works only up (1/3) of the actual width. Most likely to do with Vec3b.

One such solution suggested

```
unsigned char color = img.at<unsigned char>(Point(i,j));
or
Vec<uchar, 3> color = img2.at <uchar>(Point(i,j));
```

But in uchar cases, how can i obtain individual RGB from color and how to set color back to pixel?

FULL CODE :

```
int main() {

VideoCapture cap("Assets/test2.mp4");
if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    std::cout << "Problem in reading" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
while (1) {
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty()) {
        break;
    }
    frame = Imgfn(frame);
    imshow("FRAME", frame);
    char c = (char)waitKey(100);
    if (c == 27) {
        break;
    }
}
    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}

Mat Imgfn(Mat img) {
int width = img.size().width , height = img.size().height;

cvtColor(img, img, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(img, img, Size(3,3),0,0);
Canny(img, img, 50, 150);

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        Vec3b color = img.at<Vec3b>(Point(i, j));
        color[0] = 0; color[1] = 255; color[2] = 0;
        img.at<Vec3b>(Point(i, j)) = color;
        // so **Obtain, select, set** color
    }
}

return img;
}
```

[About the mp4][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hOBV.png

***EDIT - FOUND THE SOLUTION  -  from one of the answers suggested below. The problem is when cvtColor convert to gray is performed it brings down to just 1 channel from 3. Mat.channels() can be used to check. so a simple uchar would work fine. if 3 channels of RGB are required then one could simply created their own RGB to GRAY function***

Comment: are you sure img has three channels? what you are describing makes sense if you have a single channel Mat that you are treating as though it has three channels.

Comment: Can you give an example for a cvtColor that gives that problem? If you convert from BGR to Gray you only have one channel left.

Comment: out of bounds issue. watch your loop bounds. -- why does this question not contain any error messages? please present a [mre]

Comment: `img2.at <uchar>(Point(i,j))` returns reference to a `uchar`.
Constructing a `Vec<ushar,3>` from single `uchar` is really you want to do?
Think carefully "what I'm doing" based on the code .

Comment: ok so the loop variables are named confusingly. `at(Point())` uses `(x,y)` order. `i,j` are customarily row and column, i.e. `y,x` -- we need a [mre]. your entire question doesn't contain any information on `img`. if you have trouble accessing it as Vec3b and can only access one third of the width like that, your `img` is probably single-channel (as suggested by others already)... but you don't give us any information. speculation is tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, how do you choose the type such as { `Vec3b`, `unsigned char`, ... } ?

If you access pixels in a known Mat , you know the type at the time and you can use that. Just do it so.

Otherwise, if you are talking about a situation in which you don't know the type of pixels in Mat, you can use `Mat::depth()`, `Mat::channels()`, etc to determine the type.

Comment: I guess that using `ptr` rather than `at` is better in loop.
(Of cause, not use the `ptr` for all pixel. increment the pointer.)

Comment: no, `ptr` is **not** better. it's a bad idea actually.

Comment: My guess is : For each rows, [use `ptr` once and increment it] will be more efficient than [use `at` for each pixels].
Is it wrong? If so, I want to know why.

Comment: "If you need to process a whole row of a 2D array, the most efficient way is to get the pointer to the row first, and then just use the plain C operator [] " [OpenCV Reference Manual]( https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html)

Comment: Even if such a description cannot be found in the manual, I think that it is generally true.

Comment: OP's question was about an *Unhandled exception*, not about making things faster. that happens because OP doesn't know the element type (depth) of their Mat, and neither do we.

Comment: OK, what he needs now is to access the correct memory location.
I stop talking about efficiency. Sorry for offtopic.